# How to convert dataframe to jsonl (json lines) objects without the brackets?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, jsonlines

I'm trying to convert my dataframe to a json object, not sure why the columns has an extra bracket on them?

My dataframe has 'description', 'name', 'screen_name', 'lang' columns and I used:

```
df.to_json(orient='records', lines = True)
```

The results I got:

```
{"('description',)":"backup account","('name',)":"SuchitaHedau","('screen_name',)":"oxytocin","('lang',)":"en"}
```

The results I want:

```
{'description': 'backup account', 'name': 'SuchitaHedau', 'screen_name': 'oxytocin', 'lang': 'en'}
```

Comment: Do you have a MultiIndex? Why don't you provide a reproducible sample of your data?

Comment: @mozway actually yes. Turned out I had a multi-index! Thanks